# How to validate form field when you press tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

How does it possible to review/valid each field on the form when you press **TAB** key. Currently it works only if you start typing in the box. There is a [fiddle.js](http://jsfiddle.net/p5peypct/1/).

I'm using [validatejs](http://validatejs.org/) script with these options:

```
$('#form').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    success: function(label) {
        label.addClass("valid");
    },
    rules: {
        formFName: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        formLName: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        formEmail: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        formFName: {
            required: "Enter your first name, please.",
            minlength: "A name usually has at least 2 characters, right?"
        },
        formLName: {
            required: "Enter your last name, please.",
            minlength: "A name usually has at least 2 characters, right?"
        },
        formEmail: {
            required: "Enter your email address, please.",
            email: "Enter an existing email address, please."
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        alert('sent');
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand how this is supposed to work.  Tab **does** trigger validation but since the plugin is "lazy" by default, these triggers do not do anything until *after* the submit is clicked the first time.  The accepted answer works because it over-rides the "lazy" `onfocusout` with an "eager" version.

Comment: Yes you are right now I'm smarter. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$( '#form' ).validate( {
    onkeyup: false,
    onfocusout: function( element, event ) {
        this.element( element );
    }
} );
```

**EDIT 1:**

Or if you really only want to use the TAB key as a validator you could do this:

```
$( '#form' ).validate( {
    onkeyup: function ( element, event ) {
        if ( event.which === 9 ) {
            this.element(element);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    },
} );
```